# Is there a way to interactively turn off the legend in a python `Bokeh` plot

Tags: python, plot, legend, bokeh

[Hide legend in bokeh plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141308/hide-legend-in-bokeh-plot)

So I understand who to programmatically turn off the legend in a `Bokeh` plot, however I was wondering if there is a way to do this interactively? Sometimes I have a number of items in a plot legend, and the legend takes up  lot of space or real estate. I was wondering if there is a way to click on the legend to hide it, or some such option?

I know I can affect the legend visibility through the code:

```
 myPlot.legend.visible = False
```

However I would to be able to turn the legend on and off as I wish.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CustomJS`, here is an example that toggle legend on `DoubleTap` event:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource

t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=t, y1=np.sin(t), y2=np.cos(t)))
fig = figure(plot_height=250)
fig.line("x", "y1", source=source, legend="sin", line_color="red")
fig.line("x", "y2", source=source, legend="cos", line_color="green")

def show_hide_legend(legend=fig.legend[0]):
    legend.visible = not legend.visible

fig.js_on_event(events.DoubleTap, CustomJS.from_py_func(show_hide_legend))

show(fig)
```

Comment: Is there a fix for `BokehDeprecationWarning: 'from_py_func' is deprecated and will be removed in an eventual 2.0 release. Use CustomJS directly instead.` I have tried to read [about callbacks](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html) but seems not straightforward to interact with the legend.

Comment: Why is `fig.legend[0]` passed as parameter to the `CustomJS`, instead of just `fig.legend`? It's true that if just `fig.legend` is passed the interaction is not taking place. However, `fig.legend` is also showing up as a `Legend` object with `visible` attribute. I checked the [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/3.0.1/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#bokeh.plotting.figure.legend) - it says **Splattable list of Legend objects**; not sure what that means.

Answer (score 3):

As `CustomJS.from_py_func` is no longer working this should make the trick

```
    toggle_legend_js = CustomJS(args=dict(leg=p.legend[0]), code="""
         if (leg.visible) {
             leg.visible = false
             }
         else {
             leg.visible = true
         }
    """)
    

    p.js_on_event(events.DoubleTap, toggle_legend_js)
```

where `p` is your `figure`

Answer (score 1):

As of Bokeh `0.12.13` there is no built-in UI mechanism for hiding the legend. Your best current bet would probably be to add a "show/hide legend" button that toggles `.visible` on the legend.