# Bokeh add action tool to hide legend

Tags: python, bokeh

Since I have an overlap between the legend and the charts
I would like to add in my Python Bokeh program an action tools name 'hide' with a dedicated icon, to hide or not the legend in my chart.
What is the best way to proceed ?
[image]

Comment: Is a option to you to move the legend above or below the chart?

Comment: This is a  good idea. The problem is that I have several type of charts (datetime, histo and map) and I am trying to have the same figure size. If I move the legend it will change the size of the chart.

Comment: I see. But you could move the legend on all figures instead of jusst one. So it`s the same everythere.

Comment: thanks but for an esthetic point of view I prefer not.  I will use double tab event by default see my answer

Comment: This partially answers my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511036/is-there-a-way-to-interactively-turn-off-the-legend-in-a-python-bokeh-plot